# App is crashing while using drag & drop in UITableView iOS [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am applying drag and drop feature of `UITableView`. But getting below mentioned error.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 'Attempted to scroll the table view to an out-of-bounds row (3) when there are only 1 rows in section 0.
```

[image]

my code is as below:

on `ViewDidLoad()`

```
        tableView.dragDelegate = self
        tableView.dragInteractionEnabled = true
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
```

here is table delegates

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {
        let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: NSItemProvider())
       // dragItem.localObject = data[indexPath.row]
        return [ dragItem ]
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
     
   // Here I am updating record in local db and properly updating....
        
     
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        print("Drag from :\(sourceIndexPath.section) and Record Number:\(sourceIndexPath.row) TO :\(destinationIndexPath.section)")
    }
```

Here is what exactly I want to do

[image]

after dragging it should be like this:

[image]

Comment: reloading tableview for ? sourceIndexPath automatically updated rows I guess ?

Comment: I have commented and check that also but not working

Comment: you forgot to check section as you have two sections section[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row] to assign to localobject

Comment: I have managed section as well, as I said in local db its updated already